# Why don't <s-up> and <s-down> work in :Explore (netrw) for going to previous/next match?

Tags: netrw

After executing `:Explore **/*.py` to match `*.py` under the current directory tree, I cannot execute `:Pexplore` and `:Nexplore` using `<s-up>` an `<s-down>`.

I have tried both `SHIFT+<up>` and `s+<up>` etc., but nothing happens.

Why can't I use these key bindings to go to the previous/next match?

Edit: Starting Vim using a plain vimrc (`:set nocompatible | runtime! plugin/**/*.vim`) results in `<s-up>` just moving the cursor up (likewise for `<s-down>`).

Comment: Can you explain why you can't execute `:Pexplore` with `<s-up>`? You press the key and nothing happens, or you get an error message, if you do which one? What do you mean by you tried both `SHIFT+<up>` and `s+<up>`? Did you try to create a mapping with this syntax or how did you use these two things? Also as usual, is it possible it comes from [your vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841)? Have you tried without a vimrc? And finally are you using vim/neovim/both, if you use both do you see a difference between each other regarding this issue?

Comment: @statox - I use Vim 8.2 on macOS. Yes, I tried starting Vim using `vim -u /dev/null`, but in that case `netrw` isn't loaded, so can't test it in that case. Do you know which command is used to load `netrw` from ~/.vimrc`?

Comment: You need to put `filetype plugin on` and `runtime plugin/netrwPlugin.vim` in a `tmp.vimrc` file and start vim with `vim -u tmp.vimrc`

Comment: @statox - why isn't `filetype plugin on` sufficient? I tried execute that command after `vim -u NONE`, but `:Explore` was not there. I don't have `runtime plugin/netrwPlugin.vim` in my normal `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: @statox - Didn't work for me to put those two lines in a `vimrc` and load it using `vim -u vimrc`.

Comment: Why `runtime` is necessary: Actually it would also work if you put `set nocp` in the temporary vimrc. I think that when you start vim with a custom vimrc (but without the `-u` flag) it automatically start in no compatible mode (which source stuff in `runtime`) when you use `-u` you either have to set nocompatible yourself or to source the runtime files by yourself.

Comment: About the fact that it didn't work with the test vimrc: what didn't work? You didn't get netrw to work? You get it to work but `<s-up>` still doesn't work? Or is it something else? Also please edit your question to put all this information directly in the question so that people don't have to dig the comments to understand what's going on: You'll have better chances of getting a good answer this way :)

Comment: @statox - `netrw` works now using a plain vimrc (`:set nocompatible | runtime! plugin/**/*.vim`), but `<s-up>` just moves the cursor up.

Comment: @statox - I've edited the question